# Select a particular sentence in range using find method and making it bold

Tags: vba, range, ms-word, selection

Using following code firstly I make the selected paragraph as range and then I want to **bold** text from start of the paragraph till first sentence end which in my case it is ". "

How its is possible to select the first sentence in given range?

```
Dim CON As Range
selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, COUNT:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
If selection.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) < 3 Then
selection.Font.Bold = True
selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, COUNT:=1
Else
selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, COUNT:=1
selection.ExtendMode = True
selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, COUNT:=2
Set CON = selection.Range
selection.ExtendMode = False
With CON.Find
.Text = ". "
.Forward = False
.Wrap = wdFindStop
.Execute
End With
If CON.Find.Found Then
'' Now here I want to bold the sentence 
else 
end if
```

**UPDATE**

I set the code and now it can evaluation what it is found.

```
Set CON = selection.Range
selection.ExtendMode = False
Set conFind = CON.Duplicate
'''''''''''''>>''''''''''''
    With conFind.Find
    .Text = ">>"
    .Forward = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
    End With
    If conFind.Find.Found Then
      CON.End = conFind.End
      CON.Font.Bold = True
    Else
'''''''''''''. ''''''''''''
        With conFind.Find
        .Text = "^?. "
        .Forward = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        End With
        If conFind.Find.Found Then

                If confind = "S. " Then
                conFind.Find.Execute
                If conFind.Find.found Then
                CON.End = conFind.End
                CON.Font.Bold = True
                Else
                End If

            Else
            CON.End = conFind.End
            CON.Font.Bold = True
            End If


        Else
''''''''''''', ''''''''''''
            With conFind.Find
            .Text = ", "
            .Forward = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Execute
            End With
            If conFind.Find.Found Then
            CON.End = conFind.End
            CON.Font.Bold = True
            Else
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an additional Range variable, for example

```
Dim conFind as Word.Range
```

then set it to be a *duplicate* of the original Range. Use this for the Find - if Find is successful `conFind` will be the found Range. Then set the End point of the original Range to the end point of the found Range and apply the bold formatting.

Note: I prefer to also create a boolean variable to hold the success of Find.Found, rather than testing Range.Find.Found as in my experience it's more reliable. I've left the code as you have it, however...

```
Set CON = selection.Range
selection.ExtendMode = False
Set conFIND = CON.Duplicate
With conFind.Find
  .Text = ". "
  .Forward = False
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Execute
End With
If conFind.Find.Found Then
  CON.End = conFind.End
  CON.Font.Bold = True
else 
end if
```

Comment: I am getting  'Compiler error Object Required' at `Set CON = selection.Text`.

Comment: @IbneAshiq Ah? I copied that line from your code and didn't look at it closely, assuming you provided working code. You need to change it to selection.Range.